# Rails Database seeds.rb "remembers" old data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following seeds.rb file:

```
require 'spreadsheet'



allEng1 = [] #english
allSpa1 = [] #english to spanish
allSpa2 = [] #spanish
allEng2 = [] #spanish to english
totalWords = 4999

#Lang.truncate_me!

    book1 = Spreadsheet.open('FinishedEnglishListNoDuplicatesWithFrequencyWithPOSReadyForDB6.xls')
    sheet1 = book1.worksheet 'Sheet1'

    book2 = Spreadsheet.open('finishedSpanish.xls')
    sheet2 = book2.worksheet 'Sheet1'

    for i in 0..totalWords
      vrow  = sheet1.row(i)
      allEng1[i] = vrow[0]
      allSpa1[i] = vrow[1]
      vrow = sheet2.row(i)
      allSpa2[i] = vrow[0]
      allEng2[i] = vrow[1]
    end

    for j in 0..totalWords
      Lang.create(english: allEng1[j], english_to_spanish: allSpa1[j], spanish: allSpa2[j], spanish_to_english: allEng2[j])
    end
```

When I delete everything from my Lang DB and run seeds.rb, it seems to 'remember' the words that were previously in the DB.

For instance, in my spreadsheet 'finishedSpanish.xls' I update the Spanish word 'yo' to 'Yo' but when I run the following commands I still get 'yo' in the DB:

Lang.delete_all

rake db:seed (this command runs really quickly which makes me think the old data is cached somewhere and not loading updated info)

Any idea why this is?

Comment: add `puts` to every item, for example `puts allEng1[j]` to check if they are actually being set.

Comment: All 4 arrays are being set/verified with puts

Comment: The only 2 possibilities causing such issue, is a callback that downcase the strings or that you pass the old files to the `Spreadsheet.open`

Comment: It does seem to be passing the old files to Spreadsheet.open because when I did a puts 'yo' shows up---not the 'Yo' that the file has been updated to. I do have other words that are capitalized so it's not a downcase issue. Any idea why it would pass the old?

Comment: Also, I tried changing the name of the file finishedSpanish.xls to finsihedSpanishCheck.xls and it gives me the following error "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen". Not sure why this would be since both spreadsheets are in same directory as seeds.rb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no callbacks causing the downcase, and since its impossible to remember your deleted database so the database is not the causing the problem. As `delete_all` runs a direct SQL `Delete` statement without even touching the callbacks.

Delete the all the `xls` files from your directory (also empty the trash to avoid any existence to tmp files) . Then place the new ones.